# How to find exact index of same words in a sentence?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my sample table.

`df=pd.DataFrame({'sentence': {0: 'idontlikeanapple.dislike', 1: 'welcometomyroom.plzcomein', 2: 'thisisthetable'},                'target': {0: 'like', 1: 'come', 2: 'is'}},                '')`

I want to find exact index of the target word from the sentence. (Allow duplication.)
so what i want is, for example, the index of the first row should be 5, 20 (because "like" is in the sentence TWICE).

AND, plz don't consider of using "split" for the sentence. I don't want any spaces.

i tried to use finditer, but just got errors.

Comment: please add your tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `finditer` can extract the startindex of each match in string.

Code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [m.start() for m in re.finditer(x.target,x.sentence)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    [5, 20]
1    [3, 19]
2     [2, 4]
dtype: object
```